# What does it mean by a branch penalty?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

> Branch penalty in pipeline results from non-zero distance  between ALU
>   and IF.

What does it mean by this statement?

Comment: Surprisingly, [Branch predictor - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) does a very good job explaining branch prediction (the associated models) and the misprediction penalty in great detail. Always a top contender for the first stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without (correct) branch *prediction*, fetch doesn't know what to fetch next until the ALU decides which way a conditional or indirect branch goes.  So it stalls until the branch executes in the ALU.

Or with an incorrect prediction, the fetched/decoded instruction from the wrong path are useless, so we call it the branch *mispredict* penalty; branch prediction hides it in the normal case.

Another term for this is "branch *latency*" - the number of cycles from fetching a branch instruction until the front-end fetches a useful next instruction.

Note that even unconditional branches have branch latency: the fact that an instruction *is* a branch at all isn't known until after it's decoded.  This is earlier in the pipeline than execution so the possible penalty is smaller than for conditional or indirect branches.

---

For example, in first-gen MIPS R2000, a classic 5-stage RISC, conditional branches only take half a cycle in the EX stage, and [IF doesn't need the address until the 2nd half of a clock cycle, so the total branch latency is kept down to 1 cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586551/how-does-mips-i-forward-from-ex-to-id-for-branches-without-stalling/58601958#58601958).  MIPS hides that latency with a [branch-delay slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot#Branch_delay_slots): the instruction after a branch always executes, whether the branch it taken or not.  (Including unconditional direct branches; the ID stage can produce the target address on its own.)  Later more deeply pipelined MIPS CPUs (especially superscalar and/or out-of-order) did need branch prediction, with the delay slot not able to fully hide branch latency.

Answer (score 3):

It means, you had penalty between the cycles of the processor. 
Every processor has cycles of operation, each delay in the cycle will result in a penalty, as it waits until the branch executes in the ALU or:

> Branch penalty in pipeline results from non-zero distance between ALU
>   and IF.

There is a wonderful, but long book called [Computer Architecture Piplined And Parallel Processor Design](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=JS-01OTl9dsC&pg=PA673&lpg=PA673&dq=Branch%20penalty%20in%20pipeline%20results%20from%20non-zero%20distance%20between%20ALU%20and%20IF&source=bl&ots=svsxOQaS-S&sig=ACfU3U1gdOL7P_ecYbTf0vQDyWZ3LG2udA&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim2_e9lMriAhUOalAKHZRqBQYQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Branch%20penalty%20in%20pipeline%20results%20from%20non-zero%20distance%20between%20ALU%20and%20IF&f=false) .

It explains in detail regarding the issue.

Comment: You mean stages, not cycles.  A "cycle" is the unit of time, a clock cycle.  During which instructions move to the next pipeline stage (if they're not stalled)

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

The penalty for mis-predicting the **next possible** branch would result in time wastage (CPU clock cycles) as

1. the wrongly predicted branch which was fetched and executed
   **speculatively** would then need to be **discarded** and
2. the actual next branch would need to fetched and executed 
   **reactively** anyway.

Long Answer:
Look up: "Instruction pipelining", "Branch prediction" , "Loop unrolling", ...

Comment: You're using the word "branch" to describe non-branch instructions on a (possible) *path* of execution.  This is confusing.  Instead say "the wrongly predicted path was fetched and needs to be discarded".  For example, Intel's description of the perf-counter event `int_misc.clear_resteer_cycles` on Skylake is "*[Cycles the issue-stage is waiting for front-end to fetch from resteered **path** following branch misprediction or machine clear events]*".  (Resteer = point the fetch stage at the correct path.)  Run `perf list` on a Linux machine with a similar CPU to see that.